# How Can I Re-Write this VBA Macro to be More Efficient? (Copy-Paste Range)

Tags: excel, vba, csv

I currently have a full code written to copy the output of one spreadsheet, into certain columns of another spreadsheet. This is part of a project at work, but the VBA codes left to me from an employee that resigned, don't apply well. It's pretty simple in theory.

What I want it to do is pull the value in BB183 from the tab *737-10_1b28_routes* in the file *737-10_1b28_routes.csv*, and paste it in the tab *737-10 Scenario 1* of file *Aero Sales Support Modified Att.1 Performance Data Attachment and Fill in Form_20220402.xlsx* in box L30.

I then want the code to take BB184, and place it in L32. I need the code to skip a line because I want to paste different data in the other line (BB697 goes into to L31 with the same repeating pattern for BB (+1) and L (+2). I think once I have a more efficient code, I could figure out the final solution, but need some help. I'm currently running into procedure too large.

I feel like it's j=j+2 from j=30:688 for the L column and BB is like i=i+1 from i=183:512.

Then the second part of the code is j=j+2 from j=31:689 for the L column and BB is like i=i+1 from i=697:1026.

Please see code two to see how it's altered.

```
Sub vba_copy_data_GCD() 

Workbooks("737-10_1b28_routes.csv").Worksheets("737-10_1b28_routes").Range("BB183").Copy _
Workbooks("Aero Sales Support Modified Att.1 Performance Data Attachment and Fill in Form_20220402.xlsx").Worksheets("737-10 Scenario 1").Range("L30")

Workbooks("737-10_1b28_routes.csv").Worksheets("737-10_1b28_routes").Range("BB184").Copy _
Workbooks("Aero Sales Support Modified Att.1 Performance Data Attachment and Fill in Form_20220402.xlsx").Worksheets("737-10 Scenario 1").Range("L32")

Workbooks("737-10_1b28_routes.csv").Worksheets("737-10_1b28_routes").Range("BB185").Copy _
Workbooks("Aero Sales Support Modified Att.1 Performance Data Attachment and Fill in Form_20220402.xlsx").Worksheets("737-10 Scenario 1").Range("L34")

Workbooks("737-10_1b28_routes.csv").Worksheets("737-10_1b28_routes").Range("BB186").Copy _
Workbooks("Aero Sales Support Modified Att.1 Performance Data Attachment and Fill in Form_20220402.xlsx").Worksheets("737-10 Scenario 1").Range("L36")

Workbooks("737-10_1b28_routes.csv").Worksheets("737-10_1b28_routes").Range("BB697").Copy _
Workbooks("Aero Sales Support Modified Att.1 Performance Data Attachment and Fill in Form_20220402.xlsx").Worksheets("737-10 Scenario 1").Range("L31")

Workbooks("737-10_1b28_routes.csv").Worksheets("737-10_1b28_routes").Range("BB698").Copy _
Workbooks("Aero Sales Support Modified Att.1 Performance Data Attachment and Fill in Form_20220402.xlsx").Worksheets("737-10 Scenario 1").Range("L33")

Workbooks("737-10_1b28_routes.csv").Worksheets("737-10_1b28_routes").Range("BB699").Copy _Workbooks("Aero Sales Support Modified Att.1 Performance Data Attachment and Fill in Form_20220402.xlsx").Worksheets("737-10 Scenario 1").Range("L35")

End Sub
```

Comment: Don't copy. Set ranges to each other.

Comment: How can I do the RANGE(BB183:BB512) copied to RANGE(L30:688) for every other L? Do I set BB equal to a variable, and L as well? I'm struggling with the syntax of that.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. The two ranges are not equal in size and every other L means?

Comment: Ok, so I have a column of data on one spreadsheet with items in box BB183 to BB512 and BB697 to BB1026. I want the values in boxes BB183 to BB512 to be pasted into boxes L30 (column L, row 30) to L688, but only the even values. Then I want the values in boxes BB697 to BB1026 to be pasted into boxes L31 to L689, but only the odd rows of column L.

Comment: Your title asks "How Can I Re-Write this VBA Macro to be More Efficient? It's a Simple Copy-Paste". The quick answer is don't copy. The body of the question is unclear.

Comment: create list of Worksheets and loop through them, and yes, do not copy/paste, do `destination_range.value = source_range.value`

Comment: "boxes BB697 to BB1026 to be pasted into boxes L31 to L689, but only the odd rows" This could be a loop. `For Each Cell in Range("BB697:BB1026"): DestinationRange.Value = Cell.Value: Set DestinationRange = DestinationRange.Offset(2): Next`. The loop goes down a column cell by cell, and puts data into another cell, which moves by 2 in each loop.

Comment: I suggest you make a worksheet variable for each worksheet that you're copying or pasting on. like `Set CopySource = Workbooks(...).Worksheets(...)`. This way you can later write `CopySource.Range(...)` instead of the whole workbook worksheet path. It will also visually clear things up for readers and will also make it easier to fix later when someone inevitably renames the worksheet.

Comment: When the data file is reliable I've done this with a set of formulas that match the data file. There are many ways to do this quickly, you may not even need vba.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inspecting cell values from VBA is slow. Writing or copying values to cells from VBA is slower still. Doing these things over and over in a loop is a quick way to destroy VBA execution speed.

It is hundreds to thousands of times faster in execution speed to grab a large range and assign the values to a VBA array in one go, and then do the processing directly on the VBA array without touching any of the cells during the processing and then when done, write the entire array out to a worksheet in one go. The larger the ranges involved the greater the execution speed improvement by processing the VBA array instead of the cells directly.

Array processing is extremely fast in VBA. Worksheet cell access is extremely slow from VBA. It takes roughly the same amount of time to write a value to one cell as it does to write tens of thousands of values to a range from a VBA array. Never write individual cell values in a loop!

Using `.Offset` is also slow and doing so repeatedly is ill advised. This problem is avoided completely by using the array approach.

The following routine should do the trick if I understand your range descriptions adequately. `vSrc` and `vDst` are 2D VBA arrays. All the values are processed in the arrays (not on the sheets) and then when done the array values are written to the destination worksheet in one go...

```
Sub vba_copy_data_GCD()

    Dim c&, i&, vSrc, vDst

    Const SRC_GAP& = 514
    Const SRC_RANGE$ = "bb183:bb1026"
    Const SRC_SHEET$ = "737-10_1b28_routes"
    Const SRC_WORKB$ = "737-10_1b28_routes.csv"
    
    Const DST_RANGE$ = "l30:l688"
    Const DST_SHEET$ = "737-10 Scenario 1"
    Const DST_WORKB$ = "Aero Sales Support Modified Att.1 Performance Data Attachment and Fill in Form_20220402.xlsx"


    vSrc = Workbooks(SRC_WORKB).Worksheets(SRC_SHEET).Range(SRC_RANGE).Value2
    
    With Workbooks(DST_WORKB).Worksheets(DST_SHEET).Range(DST_RANGE)
        vDst = .Value2

        For i = 1 To UBound(vDst) \ 2 Step 2
            c = c + 1
            vDst(i + 0, 1) = vSrc(c, 1)
            vDst(i + 1, 1) = vSrc(c + SRC_GAP, 1)
        Next
    
        .Value2 = vDst
    End With
        
End Sub
```

Comment: For some reason, I am getting an error (subscript out of range) with the line                   'vDst(i + 1, 1) = vSrc(i + SRC_GAP, 1)'. @ExcelHero

Comment: What's the value of `i` when the error occurs?

Comment: I added `Debug.Print i` to check and the only value using ctrl+g is 0 that's shown. Is that the best way to check what value `i` has stopped at?

Comment: Just hover the mouse cursor over the `i` variable when the code execution stops due to the error.

Comment: So simple yet I missed it. `i=5` It also says `vDst(i+1,1) = Empty` (I think this is right though because that column is currently blank on the destination spreadssheet?). vSrc has a value of 2856 though.

Answer (score 0):

Given how sure I am of what you want, please make sure your files are backed-up before trying this:

```
Sub vba_copy_data_GCD()
    Dim srcWS as Worksheet
    Dim destWS as Worksheet
    Dim i as Long, j as Long

    Set srcWS = Workbooks("737-10_1b28_routes.csv").Worksheets("737-10_1b28_routes")
    Set destWS = Workbooks("Aero Sales Support Modified Att.1 Performance Data Attachment and Fill in Form_20220402.xlsx").Worksheets("737-10 Scenario 1")

    For i = 0 to 329 Step 2
        With destWS
            .Range("L30").Offset(i,0).Value2 = srcWS.Range("BB183").Offset(j,0).Value2
            .Range("L31").Offset(i,0).Value2 = srcWS.Range("BB697").Offset(j,0).Value2
        End With
        j = j + 1
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Good Answer! Although I think the upper bound of the loop is wrong. As is, L30 goes until L358 but OP mentioned L688 as the expected range. Also, BB183 goes until BB347, but OP mentioned the expected endpoint to be BB512

Comment: @Toddelson, I think you are right. The paste into the second sheet stopped at L359. I need it to keep going to L689. How can I modify the code to continue?

Comment: The upper bound of the loop should be doubled. Everything else is well written and should work perfectly once the loop is adjusted.

Comment: BB2016 was not mentioned previously - increase the upper limit in the "For i=" line according to what you need.

Comment: This is extremely inefficient code. You should never access individual cells in a LOOP. Work with 2D arrays instead!

Comment: How could this be modified then @ExcelHero ?

Comment: Please see my answer...

Comment: The j variable is there to ensure that the values are copied, row by row, from the source worksheet (as the i variable increments in steps of 2 to track every 2nd row of the destination worksheet).

Comment: Well, i goes from 0 to 2 to 4 to 6 etc, so (i+1) would go from 1 to 3 to 5 to 7, i.e. by tracking i it would retain the same step increment as i